# My function runs twice whilst meant to run once

Tags: autoit

My function is `keysend()`:

- Receives a char value as `$ch`.
- Opens a text file with comma as delimiters.
- Through `StringSplit()` generates a string array.
- Using `Case` statements compares `$ch` to 17 cases. Based on matching case passes array element as argument to `Send()`.

It runs twice whilst meant to run once. Why would it execute twice?

```
Func keysend($ch)   ; translate the character into a keystroke and send it out
   MsgBox (0, "$ch is: ","$ch is: " & $ch)
   $file = FileOpen($filepath, 0)

   if FileExists($filepath) Then

      ; Check if file opened for reading OK
      If $file = -1 Then
          MsgBox(0, "Error", "Unable to open file.")
          Exit
      EndIf

      ; Read in lines of text until the EOF is reached
      $line = FileReadLine($file)

      MsgBox(0, "Line from file is:", $line)

      ; Split the string using the delimeter into an array
      Local $userconfigasstring = $line

      $userconfigasarray = StringSplit($userconfigasstring, ',')
      Local $userconfigasarraysize = UBound($userconfigasarray)

      MsgBox (0, "Array size: ", "Array size is: " & $userconfigasarraysize)

      If IsArray($userconfigasarray) Then
          For $i = 0 to $userconfigasarraysize - 1
            MsgBox (0, "$userconfigasarray", "$userconfigasarray["&$i&"] is: "&$userconfigasarray[$i])
          Next

          Switch $ch
           Case "A"
               MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[1])
               ;$myvar = $userconfigasarray[1]
               Send("{"& $userconfigasarray[1] &"}")
               MsgBox (0, "SEND STATUS", "SEND HAS BEEN CALLED")
               ;Exit
           Case "B"
               MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[2])
               $myvar = $userconfigasarray[2]
               ;send("{LEFT}")
               send("{"& $myvar &"}")
            Case "C"
               MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[3])
               $myvar = $userconfigasarray[3]
               send("{"& $myvar &"}")
           Case "D"
               MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[4])
               $myvar = $userconfigasarray[4]
               send("{"& $myvar &"}")
           Case "E"
               MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[5])
               $myvar = $userconfigasarray[5]
               send("{"& $myvar &"}")
           Case "F"
               MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[6])
               $myvar = $userconfigasarray[6]
               send("{"& $myvar &"}")
               ;loggit("SEND STATUS - SEND HAS BEEN CALLED")
           Case "G"
               MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[7])
               $myvar = $userconfigasarray[7]
               send("{"& $myvar &"}")
           Case "H"
               MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[8])
               $myvar = $userconfigasarray[8]
               send("{"& $myvar &"}")
           Case "1"
               MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[9])
               $myvar = $userconfigasarray[9]
               send("{"& $myvar &"}")
           Case "2"
               MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[10])
               $myvar = $userconfigasarray[10]
               send("{"& $myvar &"}")
           Case "3"
               MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[11])
               $myvar = $userconfigasarray[11]
               send("{"& $myvar &"}")
           Case "4"
               MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[12])
               $myvar = $userconfigasarray[12]
               send("{"& $myvar &"}")
           Case "5"
               MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[13])
               $myvar = $userconfigasarray[13]
               Send("{"& $myvar &"}")
           Case "6"
               MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[14])
               $myvar = $userconfigasarray[14]
               send("{"& $myvar &"}")
           Case "7"
               MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[15])
               $myvar = $userconfigasarray[15]
               send("{"& $myvar &"}")
           Case "8"
               MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[16])
               $myvar = $userconfigasarray[16]
               send("{"& $myvar &"}")
           Case "9"
               MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[17])
               $myvar = $userconfigasarray[17]
               send("{"& $myvar &"}")
           Case Else
               MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", "Can't handle '" & $ch & "' <0x" & Hex(Asc($ch), 2) & ">")
               ;loggit("Can't handle '" & $ch & "' <0x" & Hex(Asc($ch), 2) & ">")

         EndSwitch

      EndIf

      FileClose($file)
      MsgBox (0, "keysend status", "END OF keysend and FileClose($file) has been closed")
      ;Exit

   Else
       MsgBox(0, "Error", "FILE DOES NOT EXIST")
       Exit
   EndIf

EndFunc
```

Buffer gets filled with incoming stream until there's a CR, whereupon the part up to and including the CR is removed and processed. Where `keysend()` is called:

```
While 1
    ;ManageTray()
    ;Sleep(50)  ; (to allow script to make way for other software. Not sure if it does though?)
    $inbuff = $inbuff & _Commgetstring()
    loggit("$inbuff & _Commgetstring() is: " & $inbuff)

    If @error <> 0 then loggit("Error returned by _Commgetstring()")
    ;loggit("@error is: " & @error)

    $n = StringInStr($inbuff, @CR)
    loggit("$n is: " & $n)

    if $n > 0 Then  ; found CR
        ;loggit("$n is: " & $n)

        ;$inbuff - The string to evaluate.
        ;@LF - The substring to search for or the character position to start the replacement.
        ;"" - The replacement string.
        $inbuff = StringReplace($inbuff, @LF, "")
        loggit("$inbuff using StringReplace is: " & $inbuff)
        loggit("Received i.e. StringLeft($inbuff, $n-1) " & StringLeft($inbuff, $n-1) )
        loggit("$packetID is: " & $packetID)

        ;If StringInStr($inbuff, $packetID) And StringInStr($inbuff, $remoteID) Then
        If StringInStr($inbuff, $packetID) Then
            loggit( "$inbuff in StringInStr($inbuff, $packetID) " & $inbuff)
            loggit( "StringMid($inbuff, $n-1, 1) in StringInStr($inbuff, $packetID) is: " & StringMid($inbuff, $n-1, 1))
            keysend(StringMid($inbuff, $n-1, 1) ); process the char before the CR
        EndIf

        $inbuff = StringTrimLeft($inbuff, $n)   ; inbuff holds everything after the CR
        loggit( "$inbuff after StringTrimLeft($inbuff, $n) is: " & StringTrimLeft($inbuff, $n))

    ;Else
      ;loggit( "$n is not greater than i.e. $n is: " & $n )
    EndIf
WEnd
```

Outcomes of `loggit()`:

```
26-06-2013 09:09:48.723--> $inbuff & _Commgetstring() is:
UCAST:000D6F0001B557E3,07=RFC-951

26-06-2013 09:09:48.724--> $n is: 1
26-06-2013 09:09:48.725--> $inbuff using StringReplace is:
UCAST:000D6F0001B557E3,07=RFC-951

26-06-2013 09:09:48.726--> Received i.e. StringLeft($inbuff, $n-1)
26-06-2013 09:09:48.727--> $packetID is: UCAST:
26-06-2013 09:09:48.729--> $inbuff in StringInStr($inbuff, $packetID)
UCAST:000D6F0001B557E3,07=RFC-951

26-06-2013 09:09:48.730--> StringMid($inbuff, $n-1, 1) in StringInStr($inbuff, $packetID) is:
26-06-2013 09:09:53.147--> $inbuff after StringTrimLeft($inbuff, $n) is: CAST:000D6F0001B557E3,07=RFC-951
```

`_Commgetstring()`:

```
;================================================================================
; Function Name:  _CommGetstring()
; Description:    Get whatever characters are available received by the port for the selected channel
; Parameters:     none
; Returns:  on success the string and @error is 0
;           if input buffer empty then empty string returned
;           on failure an empty string and @error set to the error set by DllCall
; Notes: Use _CommGetLine to get a whole line treminated by @CR or a defined character.
;=================================================================================
Func _Commgetstring()
    ;get a string NB could be part of a line depending on what is in buffer
    Local $vDllAns

    If Not $fPortOpen Then
        SetError(1)
        Return 0
    EndIf

    ;$sStr1 = ''
    ;$vDllAns = DllCall($hDll,'str','GetByte')
    $vDllAns = DllCall($hDll, 'str', 'GetString')

    If @error <> 0 Then
        SetError(1)
        mgdebugCW('error in _commgetstring' & @CRLF)
        Return ''
    EndIf
    Return $vDllAns[0]
EndFunc   ;==>_Commgetstring
```

`loggit()` and `stamp()`:

```
$logfile = "file.log" ; this is a .txt file

func stamp()    ; provide a timestamp for the log file
    return @MDAY & "-" & @MON & "-" & @YEAR & " " & @HOUR & ":" & @MIN & ":" & @SEC & "." & @MSEC & "--> "
EndFunc

Func loggit($logarg)
    FileWriteLine($logfile,stamp() & $logarg & @CRLF)
EndFunc
```

- [`loggit()` content](https://gist.github.com/AMonari1/6a9578fa381e414a6aba)
- [`keysend()`](https://gist.github.com/AMonari1/53cb82d6cc338243f6be)
- [`theCommgetstring()`](https://gist.github.com/AMonari1/5e99529f70b72207dde5)

Comment: Well the problem is with the code calling this function. If you take the above code and call the function on its own then there is no problem. Please can you provide code that actually shows the error.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for the reply. I've indicated where the function keysend() is being called. As I mentioned above, the idea is that the buffer - gets filled with bits of the incoming stream until there's a CR in it, whereupon the part up to and including the CR is removed and processed i.e. passed on to function keysend().

Comment: What does the log say `_Commgetstring()` is? The logic is sound unless there is an @LF without an @CR (in which case after StringReplace $n will not be the index to the @CR.

Comment: HI matt, thanks for the reply. Above I've indicated what the log for the _Commgetstring() returns i.e. $inbuff & _Commgetstring() is: 
UCAST:000D6F0001B557E3,07=RFC-951

Comment: I still can't seem to reproduce. I put together a working version of your code [here](https://gist.github.com/MattDiesel/5866187) that runs as expected (apart from a couple of minor bugs, you were checking the @error result from `_Commgetstring` after a call to `loggit` which would never work). Is there any chance that `_Commgetstring` returns the same value twice?

Comment: Hi Matt, I've posted the _Commgetstring() code above and I doubt it is executing twice

Comment: And could you add more output from loggit, that shows the logs when the function is called twice?

Comment: Hi Matt, I've added my function loggit as an edit and apologies but when you mean more output from loggit, do you mean call loggit from within lets say the case statement. Thanks.

Comment: No, I meant when you say "Below are the outcomes of the loggit:" it lists the output for a single iteration, so doesn't actually show the function being called twice.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the reply. Essentially the above loggit was after the program received the packet containing the $ch value. I've added another loggit() iteration as an edit. My line of thinking was as I'm calling the Commgetstring() and the keysend() in a while loop, I'll ensure that I'm always able to watch out for an incoming packet with the $ch value. I've posted links as an edit for the contents of the log file, the file containing the keysend and the file containing the Commgetstring().

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the reply. Also having gone through the log file again i.e. the one I posted on github gists, I'm also suspecting I'm having issues with reading the $ch value properly the very first time of asking i.e. the $ch file seems not be read and then read hence my initial suspicion that the function keysend is being executed twice.