# Re-writing AutoIt code in a more Java friendly scripting language

Tags: java

I've got AutoIt code/program which is required to run in the background and I've been trying to integrate with Java with little success as seen in my earlier post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295428/function-executing-twice-in-autoit).

Essentially I would like to re-write this in another scripting language that is more friendly with Java.

Which other "easy-to-understand" AutoIt alternatives that are preferably easy to integrate with Java exist?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not rewrite it directly in Java?

Comment: @stonedsquirrel, thanks for the reply. I haven't thought deeply into writing it in java as I honestly don't know in java much about dealing with COM ports and dll files in java plus most importantly sending simulated keystrokes to the currently open windows (see here http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm on how autoit does it) which is the fundamental functionality of the AutoIt program I posted here https://gist.github.com/AMonari1/53cb82d6cc338243f6be

Comment: But you'd have to learn that in any other new language too ;-) But yeah, it sounds like something you don't want to do in Java. Maybe C is a good option. As far as I know you can call compiled C code relatively easy from Java. But I haven't done it myself.